# Hash value always different on same input

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I'm trying to use [this hashing function](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) but each time I reload the page it gives me a different string, except for the first 7 characters.

```
<?php  
require("lib/password.php")  
$pass = $_POST['input_password'];
echo 'Received: '.$pass.'<br />';
$passwordHash = 'default';   
$passwordHash = password_hash(trim($pass), PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ["cost" => 11]);   
echo 'Password hash is '.$passwordHash;
```

For example I pass over aaa and get the hashes

```
$2y$11$1Ll4twbmFNWhVxBOCeDWhOtZ4WchW.GYXK3LSH9BnW6AhXf45soWq
$2y$11$H0dmOkkq3rSgggDbGueRPusODmkZrrFqG7I/R1B0tFTQEYGHB0iZi
$2y$11$z0pFOoFsD5Bk0sx2TiT3kOd2awAwDBQAsQaxlDq11kNH.ldaS1qw2
```

I'm using WAMP Server 2.2 on Windows 7 64 bit and Firefox 17.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the developer? It looks like it's doing something with random numbers [here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php#L103).

Comment: Do not `trim()` the password: This may confuse the user, who enters the password ;)

Comment: It's supposed to do this. What is the problem?

Comment: @TylerCrompton: I am the developer. And this is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing. The hash should be different for every single execution. That's the point of a salt (so the same password hashes differently for each user)...

Comment: FYI, as far as I can tell the line `$passwordHash = 'default';` in the question code does nothing and can be removed.

Comment: How cool is it to have the developer in on the discussion.

Comment: Note the `["cost" => 11]` syntax only works in PHP 5.4+.

Comment: @DWright That's one of the cool things about SO :)

Comment: I didn't realize there was a function to do this for me and thought I had to rehash every password attempt and compare it myself.

Comment: @KingCrunch how come? Because the user would get confused if he can enter spaces before his password?

Comment: @Celeritas: What if the spaces are part of his password?  Don't modify the password entered.  If they typed it wrong, they typed it wrong.

Comment: Please allow NUL-chars and whitespace in passwords, a not so small amount of users is actually using it for their passwords.

Comment: @hakre 1)maybe in the middle of passwords but I doubt the beginning or end 2)how do you know this?

Comment: @Celeritas: I know this because I reversed real-user password-hashes, so this was actually a tip from developer to developer. Not all users are as dumb as we think from time to time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That hash algorithm uses a random salt each time.  It's designed to be different each time, even with the same input.

To check passwords, use the `password_verify` function included in that library.

Note: The `$2y$11$` at the beginning specifies the algorithm and cost used to generate the hash.

Comment: To make it complete: The next 21 characters after `$2$11$` is the hash. As far as I remember you can specifiy a salt yourself. You can try it out and take the 21 salt-characters from one hash and you should get the same result. I recommend this only for testing purposes ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch: I didn't though the code that much, so I wasn't sure how the salt/hash was actually stored `:-P`

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The value includes a random [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) in order to thwart [rainbow table attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).